# Multselecting in Pandas using .loc

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have sucessfully used `.loc` for assignment of a column of a filtered dataset, but now I need to filter the dataset with two filters and get the following error. I am trying to use the `&` operator like you would if just filtering.

```
TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [object] array with a scalar of type [bool]
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['Arlington', 'MA'],
                           ['Arlington', 'TX'],
                           ['Dallas', 'TX']],
                     columns=['City', 'State'])

df.loc[(df['State'] == 'TX' & df['City'] == 'Arlington'), 'New Column'] = 10

print df
```

Desired output:

```
            City State  New Column
0      Arlington    MA         NAN
1      Arlington    TX          10
2         Dallas    TX         NaN
```

Comment: You need to parenthesize the comparisons as `(df['State'] == 'TX') & (df['City'] == 'Arlington')`.

Comment: @BrenBarn, You're right, thanks. Why not post as an answer so I can accept as Best Answer?

Comment: Note that you're not using the `&` operator "like you would if just filtering".  You'll get the same error if you try to use your condition to filter rather than to assign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to parenthesize the comparisons as `(df['State'] == 'TX') & (df['City'] == 'Arlington')`.  In Python, bitwise operators like `&` have a higher precedence than comparison operators like `==`.